# Parse Facebook - clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform, cocoapods

I'm using pod to add Parse framework and Facebook sdk, but I'm having those errors.

[image]

[image]

Here is my Podfile:

```
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', :git => 'https://github.com     /jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController', :branch => 'version_5.3.2_patch'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
```

How I can get rid of those errors?
I'm using Swift.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should link Facebook SDK separately. Remove also **Bolts**.framework from Parse to avoid duplicate symbols (because Facebook already contains Bolts implementation). It is a known (reported problem for example here https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/741 ) using parse and pods in parallel.

Comment: So It's better if I remove facebook sdk from my Podfile and add it manually to my project